# Как получить из массива массивов необходимые данные?

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как получить из массива массивов необходимые данные?

мне необходимо получить массив со всеми датами (выделил даты на скрине)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public function getApiHolidays()
{
    $apiDate = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/russian__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyC8khrJO57yl4szjLOuyQrlW7R_CKgwaH0'),1);

    $holidayDates = Arr::pluck($apiDate, 'items.start.date');

    dd($holidayDates);

    return $holidayDates;

}
```

почему то выдает

```html
   
array:9 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
  2 => null
  3 => null
  4 => null
  5 => null
  6 => null
  7 => null
  8 => null
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dates = Arr::pluck($arr['items'], 'start.date');
```

Comment: Почему то null выдает.. добавил инфу в главный топик

Comment: $apiDate['items'][0]['start']['date'] вот так получилось обратиться, но блин уже хотелось бы через хелпер ларавеловский

Comment: Изменил пример попробуйте так